# SeekBar thumb icon half portion get removed at initial stage

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

this is my `SeekBar` Layout Code.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_details"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_shape"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_seek_image" />
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

thumb icon half portion get removed at initial and final stage,
other wise its work fine.

Comment: can you post your complete xml layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by using the `SetThumbOffset` option. It allows the thumb to extend out of the range of the track and can be used to control the space allowed at the edges for a seek bar's thumb.

Also, you can use `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` on your SeekBar.

Example:

```
 android:paddingLeft="6dp"
 android:paddingRight="6dp"
 android:thumbOffset="8dp"
```

Reference Doc: [SetThumbOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar#setThumbOffset(int))

Comment: thanks @Abhi its working by adding paddingleft and right and without add thumbOffset.